# Can we have a radially symmetric function solve the heat eqn. without symmetric boundary data?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> In other words, if 
>   $$\begin{cases} u_t - \Delta u = 0 & \mbox{ in} \space\ \mathbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty) \\ u(x,0) = g(x) & \mbox{ on} \space\ \mathbb{R}^n \times \left\{ t = 0 \right\} \end{cases}$$
>   where $u(x,t)$ is radially symmetric. Does this imply that the initial conditions must be radially symmetric?

I know as $t\to 0$ that $u$ converges to $g$, and by hypothesis $u(x,t)$ is radially symmetric wrt $x$ for all $t>0$. Is it as simple as passing the limit using the continuity of $u$, so that our initial condition, $g$ is radially symmetric.

I can't help but feel like I'm overlooking something here.

::EDIT::

We may pass the limit because otherwise we would have that $|g(x) - g(Ox)| = C$, where $O$ is an orthogonal matrix, and $C$ is some arbitrary constant. Then, since $u$ converges to $g$ as $t\to 0$, we have that for all $\epsilon > 0$, that
$$\sup_t \left\{|u(x,t) - g(x)|\right\} < \epsilon \hspace{1cm} t << 1$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
|u(x,t) - g(x)|  &= |u(x,t) - g(Ox) + g(Ox) - g(x)| \\
&\leq |u(Ox) - g(Ox)| + |g(Ox) - g(x)| \\
&< \epsilon + C
\end{align*}

a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some sense, this can happen. For example, with $n=1$ let
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \quad &\text{if }x\ne 1 \\ 1 &\text{if }x = 1 \end{cases}
$$
The solution of heat equation with this initial condition is $u(x,t)\equiv 0$, which is symmetric (even), while $g$ is not.

The unstated hypothesis in your question was that $u$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n\times [0,\infty)$. In that case the statement is true. The proof you wrote needs work (what exactly is a contradiction at the end?). It should have been simpler:
$$
g(Ox) = \lim_{t\to 0} u(Ox, t) = \lim_{t\to 0} u(x, t) = g(x)
$$
for every orthogonal matrix $O$.